# Integral of $\int\ \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $ with 2 method

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I was asked to solve the indefinite integral using two method

$$\int\ \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $$

if I let  x=sin $\theta$,

$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx = \frac12  x\sqrt{1-x^2} + \frac12 \sin^{-1}x + C$$ ...(1)

als0, if I let x=cos $\theta$,

$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx = \frac12  x\sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac12 \cos^{-1}x + C$$ ...(2)

this should be the same no matter what I choose x to be but looks different 
as (1)-(2) != 0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: (1) - (2) isnt supposed to be $0$.  It's supposed to be a constant.  And it is $(1) - (2) = \frac 12\sin^{-1}(x) + \frac 12\cos^{-1}(x) + C_1 - C_2 = \frac \pi 4 + C_1 - C_2$ which is a constant.

Answer (score 6):

But they're equal, because$$\bigl(\forall x\in[-1,1]\bigr):\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\frac\pi2.$$Therefore, the difference between your answers is constant.

Comment: If this is surprising on first sight, remember that $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$.